# Can I determine the name of the physical server in PHP?

Tags: php, server

We have a website that is moved between two physical servers, both RedHat Linux. The site looks exactly the same, no matter which physical server it's running on.

I need to display which physical server is being used at the moment.

I tried $_SERVER superglobal, but it doesn't have that info.

Comment: That depends an awful lot on how your servers are distinguished.

Comment: you could use uname or some such thing to get the servers actual name

Comment: In some Unix platforms you can run `uname -n`.

Comment: `php_uname()`      (that is all)

Comment: I would suggest slapping the info you need into an environment variable. This will be much more reliable, safe, and work on most (any?) platform.

Comment: There is no guarantee `uname` is stable or unique at all. @CollinD is right, just tag this at deploy/initialization. Although why your running web app needs to know what server it's running at is another thing worth thinking about.

Comment: Do they have different hostnames? IE `web1` and `web2`? If so, you can try `gethostname()`

Comment: @CollinD, could you add and answer and elaborate, please? And, what is the problem with `uname`?  Why I need it? Because the customer wants to know.

Comment: `uname` will change when the OS patches or updates. Which means you'd have to fix the code if that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the host machine name use gethostname() method, which internally does a 'uname'.

```
<?php
    echo gethostname();
?>
```

Info : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: That one works. Exactly what I need. From other comments I learned that php_uname('n') seems to do the same

Answer (score 1):

Add a servanme.php (or config.php or config.xml ...) file that is uploaded with a different name on each server.

```
define("SERVER_NAME","AlphaOne");
```

It could be kept in a separate folder to lower the chance of accidentally writing over it with the wrong version.

```
require '../servername/servername.php';
```

This file could also be where you keep other server configuration data (db connections, shared secrets...)

```
<server_name>AlphaOne</server_name>
<mysql_db>customerinfo</mysql_db>
```

See SimpleXML at php.net for an easy way to read a config file of XML tags

```
include 'config.php';  // defines $xmlstr
$config_data = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $config_data->server_name;
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution. All the php files are in git and used exactly the same, no matter which physical server is being used.

Comment: @AdaLovelace good lord then how do you store sensitive/environmentally-dependant information such as database credentials?

Comment: Exactly.  Although I suggested .php for simplicity this is configuration data not program code.   It's normal to leave data (especially secrets and keys) out of git.

Comment: The two servers are redundant, and are identical. There are other servers used in the development process that have different environmentally-dependent information

Answer (score 0):

Another method might be to call the "hostname" command on the bash shell:

```
$hostname = shell_exec('hostname');
```

Comment: PHP has a built in `gethostname()` function, so shell_exec is not needed.

Comment: My company considers shell_exec a security risk